# Problemas de gerenciamento de layout com MigLayout

Tags: java, swing

Estou com problemas para gerenciar o layout de um JFrame que é um teste.

**Como está:**

[image: Como está]

**Como eu gostaria que fosse:**

[image: Como eu gostaria que fosse]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class TesteMigImagem {

    public TesteMigImagem() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        JPanel imagem = new JPanel();
        imagem.setBackground(Color.red);


        panel.add(new JLabel("Codigo"));
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "width 100%, wrap");
        panel.add(new JLabel("Nome"));
        panel.add(new JTextField(),"split, grow x");
        panel.add(imagem, "width :100:, height :100:, spany 2, wrap");
        panel.add(new JLabel("Endreço"));
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "grow x, split");

        panel.add(new JLabel("Numero"));
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "grow x");

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TesteMigImagem();
    }
}
```

Comment: Basicamente você precisa fazer uma composição de layouts, experimente usar o BorderPane como principal, dentro dele outro pane, por exemplo o FlowLayout contendo o label e o textfield do código no NORTH; Um GridBagLayout ou MigLayout contendo nome, endereço e numero no CENTER; a imagem solta dentro do EAST. Mais detalhes [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: @Math Com o [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) não é necessário fazer composição de paineis. Com ele é possível fazer designs muito flexíveis.

Comment: @utluiz você tem razão, é que eu bati o olho no layout dele e já enxerguei logo o bom e velho BorderPane, rs.. eu acho mais simples, apesar que existem inúmeras alternativas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não posso validar essa solução agora, mas segundo o exemplo da seção *Merging and Splitting Cells* do [Guia do MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf) (página 2), para fazer um "*col span*", altere a linha:

```
panel.add(imagem, "width :100:, height :100:, spany 2, wrap");
```

Para:

```
panel.add(imagem, "width :100:, height :100:, span 1 2, wrap");
```

Isso deve dizer ao MigLayout para "fazer *span*" em uma coluna e duas linhas. O comando `spany` não existe.

Enfim, como disse, não tenho como testar isso e talvez sejam necessários mais alguns ajustes, mas esse é o caminho.

---

**Atualização**

Consegui um tempinho e fiz algumas alterações que deixam o layout mais próximo do desejado, mas ainda faltaria ajustar as larguras:

```
public class MigLayoutTest {
 public MigLayoutTest() {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
  JPanel panel = new JPanel( new MigLayout() );
     JPanel imagem = new JPanel();
     imagem.setBackground(Color.red);

     panel.add(new JLabel("Codigo"));
  panel.add( new JTextField() , "width 100%, span 4, wrap" );
     panel.add(new JLabel("Nome"));
  panel.add( new JTextField() , "grow x, width :100:, span 3" );
  panel.add( imagem , "width :100:, height :100:, span 1 2, wrap" );
  panel.add( new JLabel( "Endreço" ) );
  panel.add( new JTextField() , "grow x, width :100: " );
  panel.add( new JLabel( "Numero" ) );
  panel.add( new JTextField() , "grow x, width :100:" );
     frame.add(panel);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setSize(300, 300);
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     new MigLayoutTest();
 }
}
```

O segredo é entender que o MigLayout funciona como uma tabela. Na primeira linha eu defino 5 "colunas imaginárias" ao adicionar o label e um campo com `span 4`.

Depois, basta adicionar os demais componentes pensando em como eles ficarão nessa tabela.

Comment: Boa tarde utluiz, segui teu conselho, mas não funcionou, quebrei a cabeça a noite toda e não consegui resolver o problema :(

Comment: @user8513 Consegui um tempinho e fiz alguns testes. Olhe a atualização da resposta.

Comment: @user8513 Que bom! Não esqueça de marcar a reposta como certa clicando à esquerda dela.

Comment: Ei a proposta foi comprida mais na hora que eu maximizo o frame ele perde toda a propriedade de tamanho dos componentes, ja tentei coloca `width 100%` e mesmo assim num vai, sera que poderia me ajuda denovo? gostaria de quando aumentar o frame os componentes ja se ajustam na tela.